# Read space separated float values of matrix from text file in C

Tags: c, matrix, file-read

What can be wrong with my code below that it never opens the file. I've also tried with absolute file path but that doesn't helped me, I know physically that the file is there.

```
FILE *myfile;


    myfile= fopen("IN.txt",r);
    if (myfile != NULL)
    {
        while ( fscanf(myfile,"%lf",&test) !=eof )
        {
            printf("%f",test);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(myfile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myfile= fopen("IN.txt",r);
```

schould be

```
myfile = fopen("IN.txt","r");
```

and make sure your filesystem is as case(in)sensitive as your filename suggests (so "IN.txt" is on UN*X different file to "in.txt")

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to do like this:

```
myfile= fopen("IN.txt","r");
```

This is because the second argument is of const char* type

And here:

```
while ( fscanf(myfile,"%lf",&test) !=EOF )
```

(C is case sensitive).

EDIT:
And I'd like to suggest to use something like:

```
while ( (fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &test)) > 0){...}
```

Comment: And I'd like to suggest to use something like:

while ( (fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &test)) > 0){...}

Comment: +1 Good suggestions and Welcome to SO! You can add to your answer by clicking "edit".

Comment: I can't believe that, I was using the Gnu C compiler integrated with Code Block. Isn't the compiler/linker supposed to warn me about that. As a result programaticaly what I do is completely wrong nowhere in program "r" is declared but it still compiles, weird!

Comment: You can edit your source in any editor, but I suggest you to compile it from terminal.

Tips, to do it open a terminal and move on the folder who contains your file .c. Then you have to type:

gcc -Wall -o myProgram yourfile.c

Comment: Interesting, its sure that you have some suspicion that there is the mis-communication from IDE to compiler/linker etc.. so that's way you are suggesting it, right?

Comment: Yes, you perfectly caught what I mean! But mine is just a little tip, since I think that compiling from terminal is less chaotic than doing it from IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the error using

printf ("Error opening file : %s\n",strerror(errno));